# How do emblems work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-emblems

[Jace, Unraveler of Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Unraveler%20of%20Secrets%5d) allows you to create an emblem that will cause the first spell to be countered every turn for your opponents.  Does this continue even if he is destroyed? Is there a way to counter or remove its effect?

Answer (score 8):

The Emblem will stay forever, even if Jace is destroyed.

> 113. Emblems
>
> > 113.1. Some effects put emblems into the command zone. An emblem is a marker used to represent an object that has one or more abilities, but no other characteristics.
> >
> > 113.2. An effect that creates an emblem is written “[Player] gets an emblem with [ability].” This means that [player] puts an emblem with [ability] into the command zone. The emblem is both owned and controlled by that player.
> >
> > 113.3. An emblem has no characteristics other than the abilities defined by the effect that created it. In particular, an emblem has no name, no types, no mana cost, and no color.
> >     113.4. Abilities of emblems function in the command zone.
> >
> > 113.5. An emblem is neither a card nor a permanent. Emblem isn’t a card type.

There is nothing in the game currently that can remove an emblem. (Other than restarting the game with [Karn Liberated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%20Liberated%5d)). There shouldn't be any rule preventing the existence of a card that said something like "Exile target Emblem", but no such thing exists.

Comment: Restarting the game (i.e. with Karn Liberated) will, depending on your definition, get rid of the emblem.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Karn seems to just ruin every statement that starts with "there's no way to..."